# How do I edit .js source files in AjaxControlToolkit?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working with the VS2008 version of the source code for AjaxControlToolkit. There are some changes I need to make to the javascript base files (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js, etc...) but I can't seem to find where they are generated from.

I know what changes I need to make, but I can't find which files it is that the toolkit is compiling from.

Since we need to make some changes to the functionality of the toolkit, and also because we're working with VS2008, we can't use the NuGet version of the toolkit. The project is in ASP.NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: I would advise against this strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took quite a bit of searching, but eventually reading through the build steps in the .csproj file I found where I needed to look. The relevant .js files are located in the `Client\ScriptOutput\Embed` folder of the source zip. These contain most of the necessary JS but note that the build process of the Ajax Control Toolkit will add extra locale-specific resources onto the end of these files.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain scripts that are a part of the ASP.NET AJAX framework.  I'm not sure how exactly you can go about changing those, as they are embedded in the framework.  I'm not sure if MS released the System.Web.Extensions code base, but that's where the script comes from.  Internally, the ScriptManager control renders this script to the client.

Comment: I can see that it's not using the scripts from System.Web.Extensions; our previous version of ACT (we're currently trying to upgrade to the latest .NET 3.5 release of ACT) was doing that and worked fine. The new version generates copies of the AJAX framework scripts that have a header saying `Assembly: AjaxControlToolkit`; if I could get it to use the System.Web.Extensions files again that would be ideal.